# Prove that if $f:[a,+\infty [\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then $\lim_{x\to +\infty }f(x)=+\infty $

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show that if $f:[a,+\infty [\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then $\lim_{x\to +\infty }f(x)=+\infty $. I spend very much time on it, and I can't conclude. How can I find a $\delta>0$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ if $|x-y|<\delta$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ ?

Comment: A constant function $f:x \mapsto c$ is uniformly continuous but $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty }f(x)=c$ is finite.

Comment: it seems the question is wrong.

Comment: Therefore, should be closed as "unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constant function $f:x \mapsto c$ is uniformly continuous but $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty }f(x)=c$ is finite.